# TL update affects fixme handling of options?

Tags: errors, texlive, xkeyval, fixme, xkvltxp

A few hours ago, the following code worked fine (albeit in a larger document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xkvltxp}
\RequirePackage[draft,envface=\itshape,marginface={\footnotesize\setlength{\baselineskip}{1em}}]{fixme}   

\begin{document}

  This is some text.

\end{document}
```

This was using TeX Live 2014 with updates a couple of days old.

A few minutes ago, I updated TeX Live and discovered that the code fails:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./prawf3.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkvltxp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@nomath ...e \@font@warning {Command \noexpand #1
                                                  invalid in math mode}\fi 
l.4 

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The culprit appears to be `\footnotesize`. That is, the following compiles without error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xkvltxp}
\RequirePackage[draft,envface=\itshape,marginface={\setlength{\baselineskip}{1em}}]{fixme}  

\begin{document}

  This is some text.

\end{document}
```

However, in the class file this came from, I have to remove the `marginface` key altogether. If I only remove the font size command, I get complaints about `\else` be an undefined control sequence. Moreover, precisely this code for the font size is included in the default options executed by `fixme.sty`:

```
\ExecuteOptionsX[fx]<%
  mode,status,lang,log,note,face,layout,envlayout,targetlayout>{%
  mode=singleuser,%
  status=final,%
  lang=english,%
  langtrack=false,%
  defaultlang=english,%
  nosilent,%
  author=fixme,%
  target=thepage,%
  layout=margin,%
  innerlayout={layout=inline},%
  envlayout=plain,%
  targetlayout=plain,%
  inlineface=\bfseries,%
  marginface=\footnotesize,%
  envface=\bfseries,%
  targetface=\itshape}
```

For what it is worth, here is the output from the TeX Live update listing the updated packages:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/backups
[ 1/29, ??:??/??:??] update: biblatex [6723k] (34385 -> 34433) ... done
[ 2/29, 00:18/01:21] update: biblatex-true-citepages-omit [72k] (33305 -> 34437) ... done
[ 3/29, 00:23/01:43] update: bidi [3069k] (33647 -> 34458) ... done
[ 4/29, 00:28/01:26] update: cd [85k] (15878 -> 34452) ... done
[ 5/29, 00:30/01:32] update: context-letter [25k] (31331 -> 34432) ... done
[ 6/29, 00:34/01:44] update: context-simpleslides [858k] (28300 -> 34438) ... done
[ 7/29, 00:37/01:44] update: cuisine [266k] (15878 -> 34453) ... done
[ 8/29, 00:39/01:47] update: dehyph-exptl [298k] (34404 -> 34459) ... done
[ 9/29, 00:41/01:50] update: documentation [95k] (34417 -> 34426) ... done
[10/29, 00:48/02:07] update: dvips [610k] (34213 -> 34421) ... done
[11/29, 00:51/02:09] update: europecv [628k] (15878 -> 34454) ... done
[12/29, 00:54/02:09] update: grundgesetze [231k] (33289 -> 34439) ... done
[13/29, 01:02/02:26] update: hyph-utf8 [1675k] (33887 -> 34440) ... done
[14/29, 01:06/02:18] update: hyphen-base [22k] (31131 -> 34424) ... done
[15/29, 01:08/02:22] update: kotex-oblivoir [358k] (34243 -> 34430) ... done
[16/29, 01:13/02:28] update: media9 [4989k] (34386 -> 34456) ... done
[17/29, 01:21/02:03] update: newpx [914k] (33379 -> 34431) ... done
[18/29, 01:30/02:11] update: pdftex [2871k] (34215 -> 34421) ... done
[19/29, 01:36/02:03] update: pst-func [2945k] (34156 -> 34441) ... done
[20/29, 01:41/01:55] update: tetex [383k] (34229 -> 34421) ... done
[21/29, 02:00/02:15] update: tex4ht [872k] (33926 -> 34450) ... done
[22/29, 02:05/02:16] update: texlive-docindex [204k] (34396 -> 34445) ... done
[23/29, 02:08/02:18] update: texlive-scripts [85k] (34371 -> 34451) ... done
[24/29, 02:10/02:20] update: thalie [389k] (31018 -> 34435) ... done
[25/29, 02:12/02:20] update: tugboat [800k] (32478 -> 34457) ... done
[26/29, 02:15/02:20] update: xkeyval [439k] (34020 -> 34442) ... done
[27/29, 02:17/02:20] auto-install: fullminipage (34455) [245k] ... done
[28/29, 02:18/02:20] auto-install: latexdemo (34434) [457k] ... done
[29/29, 02:19/02:19] update: collection-latexextra [5k] (34302 -> 34455) ... done
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
regenerating language.dat
regenerating language.def
regenerating language.dat.lua
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat" ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat".
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def" ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def".
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua" ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --byhyphen "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua".
```

I'm guessing the update of `xkeyval` is likely to be implicated but does anybody know what is going on or of any work around? (I'm guessing this might affect more than just `fixme` though I have no idea why `\footnotesize` should be more problematic than, say, `\itshape` or `\setlength`.) I don't understand the reference in the error message to `math mode`.

Comment: My impression is that the update of `xkeyval` has introduced several incompatibilities. `:(`

Comment: @egreg :( indeed. I have a bunch of personal `cls`/`sty` files using this. (Everything I compile uses this, pretty much.) Any idea whether this is a 'feature' or a bug?

Comment: The latter, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg Why afraid? Better it be a bug than a 'feature'. In the former case, there's the possibility of its getting fixed. In the latter case, the only options are to get used to it and/or conclude that the developers have gone insane and hope somebody forks the code. The latter is a purely hypothetical possibility, of course - I'm sure that goes without saying. (And assumes you are unable or unwilling to do the forking.)

Comment: The version history just says `General: Moved several utility macros to xkvutils` which sounds innocuous enough.... What else...?

Comment: It probably breaks to the recent changes in keyval/xkeyval regarding braces handling. But the documentation of xkvltxp says "If you want to allow the user of your class to be able to specify **expandable** macros in the package options..." so I don't know if it was really intended that this worked previously - you should write to the author. A work-around could be to use `\unexpanded{\footnotesize ...}`. You could also make `\footnotesize` robust with etoolbox and `\robustify\footnotesize`

Comment: Any update on this? Just ran into the issue myself....

Comment: @Dennis Not that I know of. My custom files are apparently using `\RequirePackage[envface=\itshape]{fixme}` all of the lines with calls to `marginface` are commented out. I have not retested recently but I take it that you have and that nothing has changed.

Comment: @cfr I managed to fix it with @Ulrike's suggestion to robustify footnotesize. Interestingly, I don't use `fixme`, so I'm not sure what's doing it to me. I'll have to check it out when I have a bit more time, but Ulrike's hack worked.